# Collecting key/value pairs in Python 2.6

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.6

In Python 2.7, I'm used to collect key/value pairs from an array and return it as a hash:

```
return { u.id : u.name for u in users }
```

But it turns out it does not work in Python 2.6:

```
return { u.id : u.name for u in users }
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I avoid doing something like this?

```
values = {}

for u in users:
  values[u.id] = u.name

return values
```

Is there any better way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just pass a generator expression that constructs a sequence of tuples to the constructor for `dict`

```
return dict((u.id, u.name) for u in users)
```

This will create the same dictionary as the dictionary comprehension in later versions.

Comment: You beat me by 10 seconds to a character-for-character identical answer. :)

Comment: @Evgeny That's the disadvantage of a language with one right way to do it ;)

Comment: actually I'd say that's a nice advantage. The asker should by now be pretty sure of the right way to do it! :)

Comment: Wow that was fast, thanks a lot guys! It works perfectly now :)

Answer (score 1):

```
return dict((u.id, u.name) for u in users)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `dict` constructor takes an iterable of pairs.

```
return dict((u.id, u.name) for u in users)
```